# How to get the object for handleRedirectCallback with MSAL and angular

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I'm having an issue where setLoginDisplay never fires with MSAl and Azure B2C

```
this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
    .pipe(
      filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None)
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.setLoginDisplay();
      this.checkAndSetActiveAccount();
      this.getClaims(this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount()?.idTokenClaims)
    });
  }
```

It says that the interaction is still in progress. It acts very much like a timing issue, because I can go back to the site and it shows me as logged in.

I read that I need to call handleRedirectCallback and await it finishing before the next steps take place, but for the life of me I can't figure out what object to make the call against.

How can I access the MSAL object that has the handleRedirectCallback method?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to inject it into the constructor like this.

```
  @Inject(MSAL_INSTANCE) private msalInstance: PublicClientApplication
```